# Do Camel Splitters preserve exchange body after they execute?

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration-patterns

Java 8 and Apache Camel 2.19.5  here. I have the following bean processors:

```
@Component("foobarResolver")
public class FoobarResolver {
  public List<Foobar> resolve(Fizzbuzz fizzbuzz) {
    List<Foobar> foobars = new ArrayList<Foobar>();

    // Use some logic in here to make the fizzbuzz populate the foobars list.

    return foobars;
  }
}

@Component("fizzbuzzProcessor")
public class FizzbuzzProcessor {
  public FizzbuzzOutput process(Fizzbuzz fizzbuzz) {
    // Blah whatever
  }
}
```

And the following Camel route:

```
<route id="fizzbuzzHandler">
  <!-- XML '<fizzbuzz>' messages get sent here by an upstream process -->
  <from uri="activemq:fizzbuzzes"/>

  <!-- Use XStream to deserialize the XML into a 'Fizzbuzz' POJO instance -->
  <unmarshal ref="xs"/>

  <split>
    <method ref="bean:foobarResolver"/>
    <to uri="activemq:analyze"/>
  </split>

  <!-- Now assuming our body is once again the Fizzbuzz we can just continue as normal... -->

  <!-- Process the fizzbuzz -->
  <to uri="bean:fizzbuzzProcessor"/>

  <!-- Send fizzbuzzProcessor's output to 'output' queue -->
  <to uri="activemq:output"/>
</route>
```

So as you can see, the deserialized `Fizzbuzz` instance gets sent to the `FoobarResolver` bean processor, which turns that instance into a `List<Foobar>` and then sends each `Foobar` off to the `analyze` queue, one by one. At least thats the intention of my design anyways!

What I'm curious is: *after* the split, what does the exchange body become? Does it "revert" back to the `Fizzbuzz` (which is what I want), or is the exchange body now the `List<Foobar>` produced by the `FoobarResolver` (which is NOT what I want)? If the body is now the `List<Foobar>`, how could I reconfigure things so that the `FizzbuzzProcessor` receives a `Fizzbuzz` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *appears* to revert to the pre-split body:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SocamelApplication extends RouteBuilder implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Autowired
    private FooProcessor fooProcessor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocamelApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer://foo?period=100&repeatCount=1").setBody()
                                                    .constant(Arrays.asList("Hello", "World"))
                                                    .log("1 >>> ${body} ")
                                                    .split(body())
                                                    .log("2 >>> ${body}")
                                                    .bean(fooProcessor)
                                                    .log("3 >>> ${body}")
                                                    .end()
                                                    .log("4 >>> ${body}");

    }

    @Bean
    public FooProcessor fooProcessor() {
        return new FooProcessor();
    }

}

class FooProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String reverseMe = exchange.getIn()
                                   .getBody(String.class);

        String reversed = new StringBuilder(reverseMe).reverse()
                                                      .toString();

        exchange.getOut()
                .setBody(reversed);
    }

}
```

Yields:

```
1 >>> Hello,World 
2 >>> Hello
3 >>> olleH
2 >>> World
3 >>> dlroW
4 >>> Hello,World
```

Comment: Because you didn't aggregate in `split()`. If you aggregate the result of step 2 -> 3, then you get whatever you want. For example if you choose to join the reversed string, the string will be reversed and joined.